# NgRX store, issues fetching data

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have been doing some tests with ngrx store but having some issues:

mainly around fetching the information from the store.

You can see my code here https://github.com/FabioBiao/ngrxtTest

On the home.component.ts i try to get the contents of the store. However I'm getting a object with the name of the store and inside that object its contents.

```
        store.pipe(select(getCart)).subscribe((data) => {
            console.log('load finish on component');
            console.log(data);
            if (data && data['shop']) {
                console.log(data['shop']);
                this.items = data['shop'].items;
            }
```

I was expecting to get the content inside the store right away, but instead i need to do data['shop'] to get the store data. What have i missed for this to work in a better way?

I also tried using this

```
this.getItemsList = store.select(getItemsList);
```

with this selector:

```
const shopFeatureState = createFeatureSelector<StoreState>('myshop');
export const getItemsList = createSelector(
    shopFeatureState,
    state => state.items
);
```

But its retuning the object store. I need to subscribe to itto get the content inside the store object. Is this also the correct way?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a new selector `selectShopState` that will point to the `shop` state, then pass it to the `getCart` to get the instance of your state within this selector.

Your selector file should look like the following:

```js
import { StoreState } from "./reducer";
import { createSelector, Store, createFeatureSelector } from "@ngrx/store";

// >>>>> 1- Create the shop selector <<<<<<<
export const selectShopState = createFeatureSelector<StoreState>("shop");

//getting the whole store
export const selectStoreState = (state: StoreState) => state;
export const getStore = createSelector(selectStoreState, (state) => state);

//getting the items from the store state
export const selectStoreItems = (state: StoreState) => state.items;
export const getItemList = createSelector(selectStoreItems, (state) => state);

//getting the cart from the store state
export const selectStoreCart = (state: StoreState) => state.cart;

// >>>> 2- Then pass it here to get the instance of your shop state <<<<<
export const getCart = createSelector(selectShopState, (state) => {
  console.log("selector Cart");
  console.log(state);
  return state;
});
```

Comment: Would have swear that i tried that before...
Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the problem is in your selector functions since they are currently returning the whole state. You can redefine selectors like this:

```
import { StoreState } from './reducer';
import { createSelector, Store, createFeatureSelector } from '@ngrx/store';

//getting the whole store
export const selectStoreState = (state: StoreState) => state;
export const getStore = createSelector(selectStoreState, state => state);

//getting the items from the store state
export const selectStoreItems = (state: StoreState) => state.items;
export const getCartList = createSelector(selectStoreItems, state => state);

//getting the cart from the store state
export const selectStoreCart = (state: StoreState) => state.cart;
export const getCart = createSelector(selectStoreCart, (state) => {
    console.log('selector Cart');
    console.log(state);
    return state;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Eduardo. 
I tried that and updated the repo with your suggestion. 
Still not working for me though. The getStore works as expects, returns the whole store.
But the "getItemList" ( changed name to a better representation) returns null.

I must be missing something basic...